# Is it possible to manually trigger Kubernetes reconciliation for a particular CR?

Tags: kubernetes, kubebuilder

We have a defined a Custom resource called *Tenant* (we use kubebuilder for writing the operator)

```
apiVersion: iam.ai.com/v1alpha1
kind: Tenant
metadata:
    name: testing-tenant
spec:
```

The operator creates a few resources like namespace, roles, and rolebindings on *Tenant* creation.

Now I want to manually trigger the reconciliation process since I have updated my operator (to create a few more resources for existing tenants in the cluster)

My assumption was that the reconciliation will kick in if I add some annotations to the Tenant CR, but it is not so.

So how can I manually trigger the reconciliation process for the existing Tenants in the cluster?